# How come I get a syntax error for using a ':' at the end of a for statement?

Tags: python, testing, syntax

I'm writing my assignment in python, a simple binary calculation program and for some reason when I am executing the program, I get a syntax error, which I don't understand as I was told the ':' at the end of a for loop or while loop for that matter is essential, just like it would be for an if/elif/else statement.

The code for the whole section of that area of code is:

```
for m in range(binaryCountingVariable):
    countingDecimalVariable = m + 1
    countingBinaryVariable = ''
    while countingDecimalVariable != 0:
        countingDecimalRemainder = countingDecimalVariable % 2
        countingBinaryVariable = countingBinaryVariable + str(countingDecimalRemainder)
        countingDecimalVariable = countingDecimalVariable // 2
    print('Decimal:', i, '= Binary:', countingBinaryVariable[::-1], sep='')
```

Comment: Syntax Error line numbers are occasionally inaccurate. Please show us a few lines of code from before the `for`, as well. (or, ideally, provide a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: might be line right before your `for` statement

Comment: I'm betting on unbalanced parenthesis or brackets on a prior line.

Comment: What's the value of `binaryCountingVariable`? Is it an int?

Comment: @BenMorris:  An invalid value for `binaryCountingVariable` would not be a  `SyntaxError`.

Comment: @Kevin: it's not so much that they are inaccurate as that the error lies in the *logical* line, not the physical line. If a `)` or `]` is missing on a preceding physical line, the logical line continues onto the next physical line and the error is then found to be there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, True. I admit that I'm being ungenerous to the parser here in blaming it for "wrong" line numbers. It's not really wrong, but it seems like it from the user's point of view.